# Дождаться ответа от неизвестного количества одинаковый асинхронных функций

Tags: node.js, асинхронность

Всем привет. Задача такая:

Есть массив ссылок на файлы на удаленном сервере, нужно их асинхронно загрузить сложить в архив и отдать клиенту.

Все выше перечисленное удалось сделать за исключением одного, самого важного - сделать это асинхронно

код:

```
async function download(files) {
fs.mkdirSync(cat); //создаю каталог

var length = Object.keys(files).length; //длина входного объекта

for (var i = 0; length > i; i++) { // бегу циклом по объекту
    if (i > 10 && i < 15) { // чтобы сразу не качать 1000 файлов
        try {
            res = await save(files[i]); // вот тут то и вся загвоздка, дожидаюсь пока не сохранится один файл чтобы перейти к другому
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
}

fse.remove(cat, err => { // удаляю каталог с файлами (зачем они мне)
    if (err) return console.error(err)

    console.log(cat + 'was removed!')
})

return archiveName; // возвращаю клиенту название архива для скачивания
```

}

```
async function save(file) {
return new Promise(resolve => {
    var title = file.title.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "") + '.mp3'
      , link  = file.link
      ;

    thenRequest('GET', link) // отправяю запрос удаленному серверу чтобы получить файл
        .done(function(res) {
            //console.log(res.getBody());

            fs.writeFile(cat + title, res.getBody(), (err) => { //создаю файл
            if (err) throw err;
                console.log("The file" + title + " was succesfully saved!");

                zip.zipFolder(cat, function() { //добавляю файл в афхив
                    zip.writeToFile(archiveName + '.zip');
                })

                resolve();
            });


        })
});
```

}

Пытался копать в сторону async.parallel но безуспешно, не могу понять как создать массив с одинаковыми функциями но разными параметрами.

Помогите люди добрые, скоро сойду с ума))

Comment: Можно же попробовать await Promise.all(), т.е. когда все все промисы в Promise.all выполнятся, тогда отдавать ответ пользователю. По-моему где-то я читал что так достигается параллельное выполнение async/await. Да, [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/company/ruvds/blog/339770/)

Comment: а как собрать массив промисов?

Comment: ну через map можно, как в статье, на которую я дал ссылку.

Comment: а вообще у вас же есть функция save, которая возвращает промис. Немного поправить код, чтобы в цикле формировался массив из вызовов функции save. И передать его в promise.all.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function newPromise( n ) {
  return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
    setTimeout( () => {
      console.log( `Прошло ${ n } секунд` );
      resolve();
    }, n*1000);
  } )
}

async function parallel() {
  let callArr = [];
  
  for( let i = 1; i <= 5; i++ ) {
    callArr.push ( newPromise( i ) );
  }
  
  await Promise.all( callArr );
  console.log( 'Всё' )
  
}

parallel();
```